# The fastest way to read assemblies GUID from Assembly Manifest file

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, guid

I try to get GUID from many assemblies.

I chose the same way as Reflector read GUID - but so far it is extremely slow process. Moreover,I receive many exceptions, when some (connected) dll files are missing

```
Assembly CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
string missedAssemblyFullName = args.Name;
Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(missedAssemblyFullName);
return assembly;
}

//... and code
string exe = "test.exe";
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve +=CurrentDomain_ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve;
Assembly assembly = null;
if (assembly != null)
{
assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(exe);
if (assembly != null)
{
var test = CustomAttributeData.GetCustomAttributes(assembly);
foreach (var elem in test)
{
if (elem.AttributeType.Name == "GuidAttribute")
assemblyGuid = (string)elem.ConstructorArguments[0].Value;
}
}
}
```

How can I make a GUID reading process faster?
Is there any other way? I just want to open manifest file and read the same GUID which is available in AssemblyInfo.cs file [assembly: Guid("98c11478-7295-4c10-a97f-4b6805df6191")

Do I need ReflectionOnlyLoad method?

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the code by Vijay Mukhi, [who wrote his version of ILDASM](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/ildasm/ildasm.htm) (source code included). It parses the manifest of an assembly prett much the same way Microsoft's ILDASM does. You can then trim the code down to just the functionality you need.